# How to generate AWS CloudWatch Alarm which involves multiple Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Need to generate CloudWatch Alarm for API Gateway and Lambda functions.

For API Gateway CloudWatch Alarm should be generated if 5XX Error count is 10% of total request count at given period (e.g. 5 minutes).

Similarly, We need to add a metric if Maximum Latency 6% of total request count > 4 seconds.

For such type of metric looks like we need a combination of metric like Sum of total requests and than need to calculate percentage of errors.

We have Math Expressions/Metric math which might be used. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Its now possible to create alarms on Metric expressions from the CloudWatch Console.**

*Original Answer below:*

*Unfortunately its not possible to create alarms based on Metric expressions in CloudWatch. 
Your best bet may be the M of N thresholds in alarms, for example: 
If num_of_errors > 5 for 3 datapoints in 5 minutes.
Its not exactly what your asking for, but may be a good start. 
Best of luck!*