# AWS: Alarming on Metric Math alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently in the process of migrating some services to AWS and have hit a bit of a road block. I would like to be able to monitor the error percentage of a Lambda and create an Alarm if a certain threshold is breached. Currently the percentage error rate can be calculated with Metric Math, however alarms cannot be generated from this.

I was wondering if anyone know a way in that I could push the metrics require to calculate the percentage, Error and Invocation, to a Lambda and have the Lambda perform the calculation and create the SNS alarm?

Thanks!

Comment: currently its not possible to add alarm on metrics math expressions

Comment: It might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233343/how-to-generate-aws-cloudwatch-alarm-which-involves-multiple-metrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudWatch just released the Alarms on MetricMath expressions.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-ability-to-add-alarms-on-metric-math-expressions/

So basically you just need to:

1. Go to CloudWatch
2. Go to Alarms
3. Create Alarm
4. Add your metrics
5. Add a MetricMath expression
6. Optionally, add other properties for the alarm
7. Add the actions that you want to be executed

More information in their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html)